# How to convert sqlalchemy response to pydantic object

Tags: sqlalchemy, pydantic

I want to convert sqlalchemy response to pydantic object. I am new to pydantic and sqlalchemy. Is the `class Results` correct? I think I am not declaring class variables correctly and the way of passing result correct `base_class(result_rows)` in below code?

I have a code as

```
class tableA(Base):
    
    __tablename__ = "A"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(init=False, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]

AnyBaseModel = TypeVar("AnyBaseModel",bound=BaseModel)

class Results(GenericModel, Generic[AnyBaseModel]):
    """Generic class."""
    result: AnyBaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str


async def execute_query(statement: ReturningStatement, 
                        session: AsyncSession, base_class: type[AnyBaseModel]) -> list[AnyBaseModel]:

    result_rows = await session.execute(statement)
    return base_class(result_rows)
```

This is how I call the function

```
statement = select(tableA)
 df = await execute_statement(statement, session, A)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check it right now, but it should be something like this:

```
async def execute_query(
    statement: ReturningStatement, 
    session: AsyncSession,
    base_class: type[AnyBaseModel]
) -> list[AnyBaseModel]:
    results = (await session.scalars(statement)).all()
    return [base_class.model_validate(result.dict()) for result in results]
```

or

```
async def execute_query(
    statement: ReturningStatement, 
    session: AsyncSession,
    base_class: type[AnyBaseModel]
) -> list[AnyBaseModel]:
    results = (await session.scalars(statement)).all()
    return [base_class.model_validate(result, from_attributes=True) for result in results]
```